# How can I properly test my model (in rspec) that uses the unread gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rubygems, rspec2, factory-bot

I have an app that's using the [unread gem](https://github.com/ledermann/unread) to mark certain models as read or unread for a user. The gem is frakkin sweet and works flawlessly in the app. Unfortunately, I'm hitting some weird errors when working on some Rspec tests that involve the models that `act_as_readable` and I can't, for the life of me, figure out where to go next. I'm hoping the amazing StackOverflow community can help me out. Here are the necessary details:

### Model method

```
def unread_subscriptions
    reviews = Array.new
    subscriptions = Subscription.where(user_id: self.id)

    unless subscriptions.empty?
        subscriptions.each do |subscription|
            subscription_reviews = Review.where(user_id: subscription.subscription_user_id)

            unless subscription_reviews.empty?
                subscription_reviews.each do |subscription_review|
                    if subscription_review.unread?(self)
                        reviews << subscription_review
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    reviews.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
end
```

*This code has some obvious spots where it can be improved or re-factored which is exactly why I'm writing tests for it so please, let's keep the discussion focused on the error at hand.*

### Rspec Test Block

```
describe "#unread_subscriptions", focus: true do
    context "when subscriptions and subscription reviews are not empty" do
        let(:subscription_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:reviews) { FactoryGirl.create_list(Review, 3, user: subscription_user) }

        before(:each) {
            subscription_double = double(Subscription)
            subscription_double.stub(:where)
                                .with(user_id: user.id)
                                .and_return(
                                    FactoryGirl.create(:subscription, 
                                        user_id: user.id, 
                                        subscription_user_id: subscription_user.id))
            review_double = double(Review)
            review_double.stub(:unread_by).with(user).and_return(reviews)
            review_double.stub(:unread?).with(user).and_return(true)
            review_double.stub(:where).with(user_id: subscription_user.id).and_return(reviews)
        }

        its(:unread_subscriptions) { should be_instance_of(Array) }
        its(:unread_subscriptions) { should_not be_empty }
    end
end
```

All of the above code seems to work properly. The `subscription_user` gets created by FactoryGirl properly and has an id. The `reviews` array generated by a FactoryGirl `create_list` is legit and has the `user_id` filled in properly. As can be seen in the code above, I've tried stubbing out the methods for the `unread` gem on the `Review` class but they don't seem to be working properly.

### Review Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence :created_at do |n|
        n.minutes.ago
    end
    factory :review do
        user
        bar
        body "MyText"
        rating 3
        created_at
    end
end
```

I run these tests with `rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -f d` and get the following output:

```
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

User
  #unread_subscriptions
    when subscriptions and subscription reviews are not empty
      unread_subscriptions
        example at ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:231 (FAILED - 1)
      unread_subscriptions
        example at ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:232 (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) User#unread_subscriptions when subscriptions and subscription reviews are not empty unread_subscriptions 
     Failure/Error: its(:unread_subscriptions) { should be_instance_of(Array) }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND read_marks.timestamp     >= reviews.created_at WHERE `reviews`.`id` = 1 AND ' at line 4: SELECT  1 FROM `reviews` LEFT JOIN read_marks ON read_marks.readable_type  = 'Review'
                                                         AND read_marks.readable_id    = reviews.id
                                                         AND read_marks.user_id        = 
                                                         AND read_marks.timestamp     >= reviews.created_at WHERE `reviews`.`id` = 1 AND (read_marks.id IS NULL) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
     # ./app/models/user.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in unread_subscriptions'
     # ./app/models/user.rb:216:in `block in unread_subscriptions'
     # ./app/models/user.rb:212:in `unread_subscriptions'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:231:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User#unread_subscriptions when subscriptions and subscription reviews are not empty unread_subscriptions 
     Failure/Error: its(:unread_subscriptions) { should_not be_empty }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND read_marks.timestamp     >= reviews.created_at WHERE `reviews`.`id` = 4 AND ' at line 4: SELECT  1 FROM `reviews` LEFT JOIN read_marks ON read_marks.readable_type  = 'Review'
                                                         AND read_marks.readable_id    = reviews.id
                                                         AND read_marks.user_id        = 
                                                         AND read_marks.timestamp     >= reviews.created_at WHERE `reviews`.`id` = 4 AND (read_marks.id IS NULL) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
     # ./app/models/user.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in unread_subscriptions'
     # ./app/models/user.rb:216:in `block in unread_subscriptions'
     # ./app/models/user.rb:212:in `unread_subscriptions'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:232:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 8.88 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:231 # User#unread_subscriptions when subscriptions and subscription reviews are not empty unread_subscriptions 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:232 # User#unread_subscriptions when subscriptions and subscription reviews are not empty unread_subscriptions
```

For some reason the `readmarks` query is not getting the user id for the review (even though the review has a user associated). I am at an absolute loss as to what is going on here and really need someone's genius to get me pointed in the right direction. Thanks for any help anyone can provide. For completeness' sake, here are some facts about my environment:

- **OS**: Mac OSX 10.7.5
- **Ruby Version**: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
- **Rails Version**: Rails 3.2.3
- **RVM Version**: rvm 1.15.8 (stable)
- **RSpec Version**: 2.11.1
- **unread gem Version**: 0.1.1
- **factory_girl_rails Version**: 4.1.0

**Extra**: I am also using the suggestion in [this thread](https://github.com/ledermann/unread/pull/12) regarding the shared macro for the `wait` method. It did not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't checked your code in detail, but it seems to me that you are using the scope "unread_by" with an invalid parameter. It must be a persistent User (having an ID).

I just added an improved param check to the gem and bumped 0.1.2, so please test your code with the latest release.